# How can I replace a date in an Xml string using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rss, xmltextreader

I am trying to parse an XML RSS feed need to convert the date in an element from this:

`<lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Apr 2017</lastBuildDate>`

to this:

`<lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Apr 2017 09:00:52 +0000</lastBuildDate>`

I am able to get hold of the `lastBuildDate` element with the following code

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(rssFeedUrl);
while (reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name.Contains("BuildDate"))
  {
    // replace DateTime format
  }
}
```

I don't know how to get the value of the text in the element & then replace it with the correct format - can anyone help?

Comment: Why not parse the whole thing, find the element, replace `innerText`, and re-stringify? Or not restringify; what are you doing with it?

Comment: You should use `XElement`; it's _much_ easier.

Comment: I've updated my thread title, I don't need to use XmlTextReader. Could you show me how to do this any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using LINQ to XML, it's a much nicer API:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(rssFeedUrl);

var lastBuildDate = doc.Descendants("lastBuildDate").Single();

var lastBuildDateAsDateTime = (DateTime) lastBuildDate;

lastBuildDate.Value = "new value here"; // perhaps based on lastBuildDateAsDateTime above

// get XML string with doc.ToString() or write with doc.Save(...)
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/889SBs) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is how. I like XmlDocument. There are other ways but this will get you going.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
    public static void Main()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><root><lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Apr 2017</lastBuildDate></root>");

            XmlNodeList list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("lastBuildDate");

            foreach(XmlNode node in list )
            {
                DateTime result = new DateTime();
                if (DateTime.TryParse(node.InnerXml, out result))
                {
                    node.InnerText = result.ToString("ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "+0000"; //Thu, 13 Apr 2017 09:00:52 +0000
                }
            }
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
                xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                Console.Write(stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```